# Generating a Poisson variable independent of "time".

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

For $X \sim Poi(r,t)$ over a period of time $t$ with rate $r$, we would have:
$$Pr(X = k) = \frac{(rt)^k}{k!}e^{-rt}$$
Is there any way I could simulate this distribution that is independent of $t$ (i.e. over a unit period of time), and apply a function on the resulting sample so that the overall random variable is distributed as $Poi(r,t)$?

Comment: Do you have control over the rate? (because if yes, you can do something simple) Also, you should edit your answer to write what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Yes, I have control over the rate. What I have tried so far has been trivial: to simulate $Poi(r,1)$ and scale the result by $t$. While the expected count would be the same, a simple calculation shows that the probabilities do not match.

Comment: Try changing the rate to something else. (Hint: look at the pdf; while it is a function of both $r$ and $t$ separately, they always occur together)

Comment: Oh. I assumed by rate you meant just $r$ and not $rt$. My mistake. In the latter case, your suggestion makes perfect sense. But unfortunately I do not have control over $rt$. Honestly, I am not sure my question makes much sense, because essentially I am  looking for a function mapping integers to integers, and hence a closed form expression might be out of the question

Comment: What I meant to say is: can you change your rate parameter in your simulation from $r$ to $rt$ for any $(r,t)$?

Comment: No. I am not actually simulating the distribution if it confuses you why my answer is no. I am trying to model a random variable that is generated by the values taken by a sequence of Poisson processes with the same $r$ (over different periods of time, $t_i$ that are deterministic but unknown). I am particularly interested if it is possible to generate an IID RV at every time slot and apply a deterministic (closed form) function of $t_i$ on it such that the resultant random variable is distributed as $Poi(r,t_i)$ for each $i$.

Comment: Let $(U_n)_{n\geq1}$ be i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,T]$ and let $N\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda T)$ be independent of $(U_n)$. Then $$N_t=\#\{1\leq k\leq N:U_k\leq t\}$$ for $t\in[0,T]$ is a Poisson process on $[0,T]$ with rate $\lambda$. Of course, this requires a random functional instead of deterministic functional.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not a full answer, but is sufficiently long to not count as a comment.

If you had allowed random functions, you could do something with Poisson thinning (tossing away samples with some probability), but otherwise, no, I don't think you can do something for general rates. To see this, consider the Poisson RV Y distribution with a rate $r_0$ s.t. $0.71 > P(Y = 0) > 0.70 $. Now, consider the Poisson distribution with rate 1, which has probabilities $P(X = 0) = P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{e} ~ 0.36 $. Now, if you are asking whether there exists a deterministic function f s.t. $f(X) = Y$, then the answer is no, since there is no subset of integers that will have their probabilities sum up to an interval between 0.71 and 0.70.

Of course, you can do more if you are willing to use multiple samples of $X$ and generate smaller probabilities (to help you add up to whatever you want), you can get better and better approximations, but the best way I can think of a mapping would be to tolerate some error and plug it into a linear program to find the best mapping.